# "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" when importing certificate

Tags: java, jboss

I can successfully generate an SSL certificate and import it to my local JRE.

However when I start my JBoss server after the import I get the following message:

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect:
>   java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
>   incorrect

I am using `changeit` as the default password.